# SQL: invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Whilst writing a SQL query for an assignment I ran into this error:

> Error Code 1111: Invalid use of group function

and I can't seem to figure out why I get this error. What is wrong with my code?

```
SELECT sum.id, sum.count
FROM(
    SELECT habit.id AS id, COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM habit
            JOIN habit_done ON habit.id=habit_done.habit_id
            JOIN habit_list ON habit.habit_list_id=habit_list.id
        WHERE habit_list.id=4
        GROUP BY habit_done.habit_id) AS sum
WHERE sum.count>avg(sum.count)
```

`avg(sum.count)` gave the average of the number of completions of all habits, I tested this in a previous exercise.

I want to list all the habits that are completed more often than the average number of completions for all habits in the same list

Comment: Change to `HAVING sum.count>avg(sum.count)`

Comment: I currently can't test the correct syntax, but I guess your `WHERE` clause should be a `HAVING` clause...

Comment: that fixed the error, thank you! <3

Comment: it's only selecting 1 row now though, any idea why?